# automation account - get currently running runbook name

Tags: azure, azure-runbook

I would like to print out the name of the currently running runbook.

```
"Printing runbook name"
$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name

"Printing call stack info"
$MyInvocation.MyCommand
```

[image]
the above does not work and just returns blank.   Has anyone else got this to work?

Thanks

Comment: I was able to run the above command in my runbook and got the currently running runbook as [shown](https://i.imgur.com/CuIMMuK.png). @Kez

Answer (score 0):

[`$Myinvocation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.3#myinvocation) automated variable contains mainly the current call stack information as detailed in the given MS Doc. Make sure that you are not using it in an inline script. Because `$MyInvocation` is not available in `InlineScript` blocks, so you can't use it within an `InlineScript`.

Sometimes it doesn't work if you are using it along with the PowerShell function scripts and also PowerShell workflows in an automation account. And also check that you have PowerShell version updated to the latest releases.

I tried below command in my automation environment and was able to retrieve the current runbook name as shown.

```
$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name
```

[image]

If still the issue persists, try using below alternative approach using `Get-AzAutomationJob` command. You will be able to retrieve the runbook name with the help of `JobID` as explained below.

```
$runbook=Get-AzAutomationJob -AutomationAccountName "newauto" -ResourceGroupName "xxxxx" -Id "04465b4a-3081-4851-b055-7ce540e6af9a"
write-output $runbook.RunbookName
```

Comment: I am not running as inline script.  Also tried with powershell 7.2 and that did not run either.  details are empty,  I feel the work-around would be over the top.  this is for a standard runbook template.